# Unix grep finding file beginning with [pattern]

Tags: unix, regex, grep

I would like to find files that begin with a particular pattern i.e. the first line of file should contain the pattern, and then print the first 10 lines of such file, is there a way to do that?

Is there a way to tell grep to only search for the first line of file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to scan *all* files and get the first line, then check for pattern, finally execute a print of the first ten lines. It might get really expensive.

```
find /path/to/search \
    -type f \
    -exec /bin/bash -c "head -n 1 '{}' | grep 'PATTERN' >/dev/null" \; \
    -exec head -n 10 \{\} \;
```

The `-type f` is required to not run `head` on directories, and `grep` is redirected since we're only interested in its exit status. The second `-exec` will only be run on those files that pass the first test.

You'd be well advised to add additional tests before `-type f`, to reduce the number of files that will be scanned.

Answer (score 0):

If `awk` is an option try this:

```
find . -type f -exec awk 'NR==1 && /PATTERN/ {x=1} NR>10 {exit} x' {} \;
```

You can read the following as:

> If the first line match PATTERN then set `x`; if `x` is set then print the current line (implicit action); in either case exit after the 10th line.

Technically the last condition should be `!x || NR>10` to save some CPU cycles, but the original version looks nicer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will be useful.

```
grep -R -n "PATTERN" *.* | grep ":1:" | cut -d: -f1 | xargs head -n10
```

This will recursively search for any files including the sub-directories and filter for the first lines and then print first 10 lines for those files.